# Probem with the focus function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, input, focus

I hope you can help me, I just started as a programmer and I have a newbie problem,
I have two inputs, I want to write a series of numbers in my first input (DO) and then automatically pass to the second input (communal code).

Inputs:

[image: two input elements with floating labels and sample data]

I understand that it is done with focus but I can't get good results.
I look forward to your responses, thank you.

Comment: You should elaborate more on the problem that you are having. What did you try so far and did not yield the expected results? What is the expected behavior? You could move to the next input field by pressing `tab`. Why is that not enough?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have tried with onChangeEvent($event) and it didn't work, more or less to understand the purpose. it would be like this. a worker has a pick gun... he picks a bar code (only so that the number of the bar code is put in DO (image that passes above) ) ​​at that moment he should go to the community code input to be able to pick another code different, excuse me if I don't explain myself well, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose You have two inputs next to each other in the same dom tree level:

html:

```
<input  (change)="onInput1ChangeEvent($event)" />
<input #secondInput  />
```

ts:
//get input tag reference

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Component',
  templateUrl: './app-Component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-Component.scss'],
})
  @ViewChild('secondInput') secondInput!: ElementRef;
constructor(){}

  onInput1ChangeEvent(event: any){
let do = event.target.value;
//let suppose max length value to focus next input is 10 letters

    let maxVal=10;
    let doLength =0;
    if(!!do){
    doLength = do.length;
    let focusNextInput = doLength == maxVal
    if(focusNextInput){
    //focus next input
        this.secondInput.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    
    
    }
      }
```

After a long discussion with Mr Eliseo about the easiest and more clean code method to deal with html template directly and with less variables:

html:

```
<input #firstInput (input)="!!firstInput.value && firstInput.value.length==10 && secondInput.focus()">
<input #secondInput  />
```

**And finally I have to say thank You to Mr Eliseo for improving this answer and guiding us to get the best method to fix this issue.**

Comment: Zrelli, I like use `(input)` event the $event is the "value" if you pass to the function the template reference variable you pass the html element. `<input (input)="onChange($event,secondInput)">` -see that the second argument is the htmlElement -not the ElementRef-. Even you can solve the problem using only html `<input #firstInput (input)="firstInput.value.length==10 && secondInput.focus()">`

Comment: Yes You're right. But my method could be useful when he want to interact to input from more than one function. Thank You for your addition.

Comment: the problem I see with your code is the use of "too much variables" it's innecesary declare "doLength" nor "focusNextInput". If you can pass to a function the "htmlElement", is unnecesary also use ViewChild -beware, when we use in html some like ` (change)="function($event,templaterReferenceVariable)` in the function you received (In Angular 9) the htmlElement -you use directly `el.focus()`-. Really Ruben should use `[ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;onChange($event,secondInput)"` -in this case $event is the value of the variable-..

Comment: I promise You when I open my labtop I will add your method as second one and best practice. Thank You again.

Comment: Thank You very much Mr Eliseo for improving this answer.